# Use variable font to thin larger headings

Tags: typography, heading, font-weight

I remember Microsoft Office 2007 introduced a style of headings that got lighter as the heading size got bigger. Now we can use variable fonts in websites, what about keeping the colour the same, but varying the font weight for each heading to achieve the same effect.

[image]

Is the hierarchy of the document going to remain clear? Is the readability going to better or worse? Does this idea work?

Comment: Hi Billy, this might be a better question for Graphic Design Stack Exchange.

Comment: The hierarchy is definitely clear. I doubt that anyone would think bolder is more important than larger. If anyone disagrees, please do say so. I wouldn't say it has significant impact on readability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine. You can use thin font weights as long as the size is large.